# How to remove word limit from product name in product detail page in magento

Tags: database, magento

i want to remove word limit from product name in product detail page in magento.

```
for example in database product name is abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, but on detail page the name is abcdeffg....

bt i want to show full name as it is.
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is the code in catalog/product/view.phtml used to display the product name

```
     <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

If you get your product name trimmed

then you simply use this with out helper

```
     <?php echo $_product->getName() ?>
```

Comment: BTW usually the product name don't get it trimmed in the product  page. Obviuosly you might be using a custom theme where there's a code to limit the length of the product name.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question..but your answer is not helpfull for me.i am still have same problem ..the product name is still comes with limited words.

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical to [Magento : Issue stop limiting the product names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200778) It's likely the CSS property `text-overflow:ellipsis`. There are 3 different default template `styles.css` files with this set in my store currently. On the other answer, I show how to find the files using `find` command.