# Magento : Issue stop limiting the product names

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

We are experiencing the strange issue with our site that some of our product names are so long and its being truncating on the front its really strange ..

I have checked in the `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php`
file but it contains no limit for attribute value.
Any one has faced such a issue before please help.

Comment: how long are the names? they will be stored in a VARCHAR in the database, so they won't be able to be longer than 255 characters

Comment: they are around max then 300-400 chars i have increased the length in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php and also in the DB name column but this is not solving the issue this is the site http://ametrade.dev.icyberking.com/jackson-safety-nemesis-safety-eyewear-black-frame-smoke-mirror-universal-2.html

Comment: no the name is stored with text type field in the DB..

Comment: @ravisoni Andrew is right... Product Name is of type varchar.... its not of type TEXT...You can check this in the table catalg_product_entity_varchar. So make sure whats the value in the table for this product. BTW this is getting interesting

Comment: it's definitely a varchar :)

Comment: Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions

Comment: by the way, having a product name that big is a silly idea anyway :)

Comment: most probably CSS issue.

Comment: How css is adding three '...' dots to the end of the name

Answer (score 2):

The three dots, aka ellipsis, come from CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow)). I only know this because I use `text-overflow:hidden` on super-long SKUs on my homepage. I believe for this to have effect `white-space: nowrap` must also be set or the text be within `<pre>` tags.

But, yes, ridiculously long product title is from your product database.

From the command line, at the root of your magento installation try: 
`find . -type f -name "*css"  -print0 | xargs -0 grep -in "text-overflow"`

Doing this on my site got 24 answers. 23 had ellipsis as the setting. Lots were also in the `/js/extjs` folder, which was outside my expectation.

---

**Update:** ravisoni keeps saying this is a "coding issue" and not a styling/CSS one. @ravisoni, I believe you asked the question without enough context.

The long text is the product **"name"**. When we say "it comes from the database" we are saying that someone intentionally created this name to be too long. Looking over your site, I see these products are appearing in the Amazon Import category, so the software you are using to import the items into your Magento is intentionally making the names too long. You need to edit the software to do it OR go into `Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Products` and change them yourself by hand.

[image: Manage products grid]

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, this is a CSS issue. Go to

```
skin/frontend/default/yourtheme/css/style.css
```

and remove overflow in the class .products-grid .product-name a { } and set desired height and width. But please make sure that it doesn't spoil the design.

Comment: check this site http://ametrade.dev.icyberking.com/jackson-safety-nemesis-safety-eyewear-black-frame-smoke-mirror-universal-2.html this is not a css issue at all this a coding issue.